# Do every 3 linearly dependent vectors have to be in the same plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I know that if 3 vectors are in the same plane, then they are linearly dependent.
My question is do every 3 non-zero linearly dependent vectors have to be in the same plane?

Thanks

Comment: In order for 2 vectors to span a plane they have to be linearly independent right? So how can I be sure that two of them are linearly independent so they can span a plane?

Comment: @iSkullmao If no two vectors are linearly independent, then all three vectors are on the same line, so there exists an infinitely many planes in which they lie.

Comment: They will span a lower dimensional space – so, if they're 3-vectors, a plane or a line (all are scalar multiples of the same unit vector).

Answer (score 2):

Every direction vector on a plane can be formed by a linear combination of two non-parallel direction vectors. Conversely, the plane is the set of all possible linear combinations of the linear independent vectors.

Among 3 non-zero linearly dependent vectors, at least one of them can be expressed by the other two. Hence this vector is on the plane formed by the two linear independent vectors.

If 2 of such linearly dependent vectors can be expressed by the third, then they are all on the same line.